# How do you change a value in a hash using a variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a program to guess the job the user is thinking of, I have become stuck on a point to do with the updating of the database after the program has made an incorrect guess.
I use a variable to store the stage at which the user is, and am trying to use it to replace the value that it refers to. I've simplified the program and pasted it below:

```
@question_database = {'Does it need training?' => 'Mechanic' , 'Is it to do with sports?' => {'Is it to do with teaching?' => 'P.E. Teacher', 'Is it competitive?' => 'Athlete'} }

@question_stage = @question_database['Does it need training?']

@job = 'Mechanic'

puts "What is a question that could identify a #{@job}?"
  primary_answer = @job
  primary_question = gets.chomp
  puts 'Which job were you thinking of?'
  secondary_answer = gets.chomp
  puts 'What is a question that could identify it?'
  secondary_question = gets.chomp
  @question_stage={ primary_question => primary_answer, secondary_question =>       secondary_answer}
```

It doesn't seem to do anything at all to the database.
Does anyone know what I should do to fix this?
Thanks, Ben

Comment: Where is the code that saves the question stage data to database? Or did u take it out for simplification?

Comment: the question does not seem clear at what point do you want to change the value in the hash, and what value do you want to assign

Comment: I took out the code for simplification, would it be better if I included it?

Comment: The value for changing is shown by the question_stage variable, and the new value for assigning should be a hash with a key as a question to identify the original job with a value of the original job, and a key as a question to identify the user's animal with a value of the user's job (all of these come from the questions asked to the user, except the first job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a new value to `@question_stage` you don't change the value of `@question_database['Does it need training?']`

You might want to write your code like this:

```
@question_database = {'Does it need training?' => 'Mechanic' , 
  'Is it to do with sports?' => 
    {'Is it to do with teaching?' => 'P.E. Teacher',
     'Is it competitive?' => 'Athlete'} }

@job = 'Mechanic'

puts "What is a question that could identify a #{@job}?"
primary_answer = @job
primary_question = gets.chomp
puts 'Which job were you thinking of?'
secondary_answer = gets.chomp
puts 'What is a question that could identify it?'
secondary_question = gets.chomp
@question_database['Does it need training?'] = { primary_question => primary_answer, 
  secondary_question => secondary answer }
```

That is, of course, if I understand what you were trying to do, anyway to change the `@question_database` you need to assign to one of its keys, or change one of its values.

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that I need to update different parts of the question database, so at another time     @question_stage =     @question_database['Is it to do with sports?']['Is it to do with teaching?'], so how would I have question_stage changing and still be able to change the answers?

Comment: You'll need to keep track of two variables - `@current_root` and `@current_key`. The starting value of `@current_root` will be `@question_database`. Then you'll call `@current_root[@current_key] = { ... }` to change the data base, and change the root as necessary - `@current_root = @current_root['Is it to do with sports']` and `@current_key = 'Is it to do with teaching?'`, and continue from there...